# Looking to formula an IF statement to apply to multiple cells

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula

Currently, my formula consists of one long string for each individual cell. I'm putting together a rate card, and while the formula works - I feel like it could be simplified.

It currently reads

`=IF($I8='Rate Card'!$A4,'Rate Card'!B4)+IF($I8='Rate Card'!$A5,'Rate Card'!B5)+IF($I8='Rate Card'!$A6,'Rate Card'!B6)+IF($I8='Rate Card'!$A7,'Rate Card'!B7)`

So I have a dropdown cell that the user can pick the client, and the corresponding rate per team member populates in the one sheet.

Is there a way I can use the current formula I have but instead have a smaller statement ?

EDIT:
For a real world example: I have Client A, Client B, Client C. When user selects Client A from the drop down (Column A, Row 1 in the rate card sheet) I want the cell to update contents of Row 1. When user selects Client B from the drop down (Column A, Row 2) I want the cell to update the contents of Row 2.

As you can currently see, my if statement is updating each cell in one long statement, I want to condense this further if possible.

Comment: Looks like you need SUMIF or SUMIFS: `=SUMIF('Rate Card'!A4:A7,I8,'Rate Card'!B4:B7)`.

Comment: To make this Q answerable,  you should add some sample data (as text) and your expected results

Comment: Also, it sounds like you could ebenfit from Pivot Tables to get what you want

Comment: Thanks @BigBen - that's exactly what I was after! The SUMIF worked.

Comment: Or maybe Vlookup or Index/Match or XLookup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Question Have Been Answered Through Comment By @BigBen and the same accepted by Questioner.

The Answer Is.

Looks like you need SUMIF or SUMIFS:

```
=SUMIF('Rate Card'!A4:A7,I8,'Rate Card'!B4:B7)
```